# Rails 3 Return Array From Collection.each Block

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, loops

I'm trying to return some json to the calling action. One of the params I want to pass is an array of arrays built from looping through a collection as so:

```
render :json => {     
:rows => @classrooms.each do |classroom|
          [classroom.name, classroom.students.count]
        end    
}
```

However, this sets :rows to the entire collection as opposed to what I want:

> [[classroom, students],[classroom, students],[classroom, students]]

Is there any way of looping through the collection and returning an array in a single block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) is the right tool here.

```
render :json => {
  :rows => @classrooms.map {|c| [c.name, c.students.count]}
}
```

Comment: Indeed, I keep forgetting about all the enumerable mixin methods!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach... **[each_with_object](http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/each_with_object)** method:

```
render :json => {     
:rows => @classrooms.each_with_object([]) do |classroom, a|
          a << [classroom.name, classroom.students.count]
        end    
}
```